# Android keyboard hide edit text fields

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad, android-screen

How to restrict edit text hidden by keyboard in for the following XML layout.In this blue area is header and footer of the screen, between header and footer I have placed edit text under scroll view to get user information, and heater and footer should not be scrolled so that I put edit text fields under scroll view.

As per the following exception edit text is covered by keyboard. How can I overcome from the issue?

I have added adjust pan and resize option in manifest.

```
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity6"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize" />
```

XML Screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_reg_top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#0000A1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/test_reg_bottom"
        android:layout_below="@+id/test_reg_top"
        android:background="#BBBCCC">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test_reg_et1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:hint="text1"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/test_reg_et2"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test_reg_et2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:hint="text2"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/test_reg_et3"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test_reg_et3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:hint="text3"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/test_reg_et4"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test_reg_et4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:hint="text4"
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/test_reg_et5"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test_reg_et5"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="#E6E6E6"
                android:hint="text5"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_reg_bottom"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#0000A1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Screen:
[image]

Comment: try adding some bottom margin to your last edittext

Comment: Use this attribute in your edit text     android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan` Use this .Hope it will works

Comment: Let me feedback #M.A.Murali